# how to build egg package with cython and c codes?

Tags: python, cython

I have a setup.py as follows (other source files are available too)

```
from distutils.core import setup
from distutils.extension import Extension
from Cython.Distutils import build_ext

ext_modules = [
    Extension("fastsim",
              ["src/fastsim.pyx", "src/selection.c"],
              libraries=["m"],)
]

setup(
    name="fastsimlib",
    cmdclass={"build_ext": build_ext},
    ext_modules=ext_modules
)
```

This works fine as long as there is cython installed in the target machine. I am wondering if I can get rid of the cython dependency by creating an egg file so that I only to run easy_install or pip.

To clarify, I want to create a distribution package so that I can install the library in a machine that does not have cython installed. Or even better, can I only distribute the binary .so file (so that no cython or c code in the package)? The OS and other information of the target machine is given(Ubuntu).

Comment: I have no issue using compiled cython code on android, just include the `.so` in your package.